# Writing from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, fonts

In an Excel macro I write the contents of a worksheet row onto a Word .docx. The actual writing intruction is

`objselection.TypeText  (textB)`

This writes in an unobjectionable format.

My question is: Can I control the font ?
I would like, for example, to write in italics.

Comment: I didn't experiment. I couldn't see anything in the John Green's "Programmer's Reference" but it's not very well indexed.

Comment: You should take some time to read up on the Word Paragraph object.

Comment: Another helpful thing to do is recording doing what you want manually (Developer Tab >> Record Macro). The results aren't the most elegant way to approach things, and generally has much more code than necessary. But they do show you the relevant property and parameter syntax. You just have to cull out and adopt the bits you want.

Comment: need the detail info as [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) mentioned in step 2.. without a sample case (step 3) info, it's not easy to pin the quest..

Comment: Following the advice above I managed to produce a skeleton that enables the printing on the Word document to be controlled. I wanted to post it here but there's not enough space allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Skeleton()
'

Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim objApplication As Object
'
file_path = "E:\TUSHINO COMPANY\AAAB FIND NEW PROJECT\Breadline 2021\Customer Documents\"
sfulname = file_path & "Experimental Doc"
'
' CREATE THE WORD OBJECT
'
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
objWord.Visible = True
'
' ADD A DOCUMENT TO THE WORD OBJECT
'
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
'
Set objselection = objWord.Selection
'
' I was surprised that this is not " = objDoc.Selection"
'
' In production there would be code extracting stuff
' from the worksheet ready to write on the word document
'
textA = " This is the first write"
With objselection
.Font.Size = 12
.TypeText (textA)   ' Top of the page heading
End With
'
objDoc.SaveAs (sfulname)
objWord.Application.Quit ' This is needed to close the document
Set objWord = Nothing
'
998 xx = 0
'
ay = "Finished"
MsgBox ay
'
999   xx = 0
'
End Sub
```